# How do you access variable declared in a class extension?

Tags: objective-c, lldb

*MyClass.h*:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@end
```

*MyClass.m*:

```
// Define a private variable in a class extension
@interface MyClass () {
    NSString *name;
}
@end
```

Then later on in lldb:

```
(lldb) po myClassInstance->name
error: 'MyClass' does not have a member named 'name'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

So how do you access that variable in the debugger?

Using xcode 4.3.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`(lldb) po [myClassInstance valueForKey:@"name"]`

Comment: @rrrus yeah, but it uses the runtime, it will also work for `@dynamic` properties, ie. core data..

Comment: Does not work if what you're looking for is an ivar and not a property.

Comment: @AriX I think valueForKeypath: does return values for ivars.

Comment: It depends on the result of +accessInstanceVariablesDirectly. I thought the default was NO, but you're right in most cases, as the default is actually YES. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/accessInstanceVariablesDirectly

Comment: But I still don't think this is the best answer to the question; see my answer for my take.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to cleanly access these instance variables directly is via the Objective-C runtime, which provides the useful function `object_getInstanceVariable`. The value is passed back by reference, and could be many different types, so it's not very useful from the debugger. But your question inspired me to come up with a solution.

I wrote a category on NSObject allowing you to introspect instance variables from the debugger, without worrying about accessor side effects. After adding the category to your project, you can do this:

```
(lldb) po [self valueOfInstanceVariable:@"_name"]
IMG_4078.PNG
```

Here's the code:

NSObject+IvarIntrospection.h

```
#if DEBUG
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSObject (IvarIntrospection)

- (id)valueOfInstanceVariable:(NSString *)ivarName;

@end

#endif
```

NSObject+IvarIntrospection.m

```
#if DEBUG
#import "NSObject+IvarIntrospection.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation NSObject (IvarIntrospection)

- (id)valueOfInstanceVariable:(NSString *)ivarName {
    // Get the value of the instance variable
    // Use a union in order to convert the value to a float or double (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning)
    union {
        void *value;
        float f;
        double d;
    } ivar;
    Ivar ivarInfo = object_getInstanceVariable(self, [ivarName UTF8String], &ivar.value);

    // If the instance variable doesn't exist, try adding an underscore
    if (!ivarInfo && ![ivarName hasPrefix:@"_"]) {
        NSString *underscoredIvarName = [@"_" stringByAppendingString:ivarName];
        NSLog(@"Instance variable '%@' does not exist. Perhaps you meant '%@?' Let's try that.", ivarName, underscoredIvarName);

        return [self valueOfInstanceVariable:underscoredIvarName];

    // If there's already an underscore, error
    } else if (!ivarInfo) {
        NSLog(@"Instance variable '%@' does not exist.", ivarName);
        return nil;
    }

    // Figure out what type the instance variable is and return a sensible representation
    const char *type = ivar_getTypeEncoding(ivarInfo);
    switch (type[0]) {
        case 'c':
            return [NSNumber numberWithChar:(char)ivar.value];
        case 'i':
            return [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)ivar.value];
        case 's':
            return [NSNumber numberWithShort:(short)ivar.value];
        case 'l':
            return [NSNumber numberWithLong:(long)ivar.value];
        case 'q':
            return [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:(long long)ivar.value];
        case 'C':
            return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedChar:(unsigned char)ivar.value];
        case 'I':
            return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:(unsigned int)ivar.value];
        case 'S':
            return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:(unsigned short)ivar.value];
        case 'L':
            return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:(unsigned long)ivar.value];
        case 'Q':
            return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:(unsigned long long)ivar.value];
        case 'f':
            return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:ivar.f];
        case 'd':
            return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:ivar.d];
        case '*':
            return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)ivar.value];
        case '@':
        case '#':
            return (id)ivar.value;
        case ':':
            return NSStringFromSelector((SEL)ivar.value);
        default:
            return [NSValue valueWithBytes:&ivar.value objCType:type];
    }
}

@end

#endif
```

Note that the category will be automatically disabled when compiling for release (thanks to the debug macro).

Comment: if you want to make this a category of NSObject... ok but that seems a little heavy handed for looking at a couple of values in the debugger...

Comment: Haha, you're right again. When I commented on your answer, I didn't think it'd end up being quite so heavy. I'm wrong all over the place! But it is an accurate answer to the question "how do you access an instance variable directly," and I think it'll be useful when I'm doing Cocoa development, as I often write accessors that populate an instance variable if it's not set yet.

Comment: The first version was 4 lines, but I got a little carried away when I noticed that it didn't work for non-Objective-C types...

Answer (score -3):

If you need to access `name` from outside of the `MyClass` methods, you need to define methods to access it.  You could just write methods called `(NSString*) name` and `- (void) setName:(NSString*) newName`, but it's easier to define properties and synthesize them.

In *MyClass.h*, you define a property.  For strings, you usually make them `copy`:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (copy) NSString* name;

@end
```

In *MyClass.m*, you still use your interface declaration, with the ivar:

```
@interface MyClass () {
    NSString *name;
}
@end
```

However, you also need to *synthesize* your new property.  This creates methods for retrieving and setting *name*:

```
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize name = name;

@end
```

As a convention, it is common to put an underscore at the start or end of the ivar, so in the interface you would have `NSString *_name;`, and in the implementation you would have `@synthesize name = _name`.  This helps avoid accidentally using the ivar when you meant the property.

You can now access your *name* property:

```
MyClass me = [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
[me setName:@"My name"];
NSLog(@"Name = %@", [me name]);
```

Objective-C properties are a powerful feature of the language, but they do have some quirks you must learn.  Try a web search for some combination of "objective-C", "properties" and "synthesize".

If you still have compiler errors, please edit your question with the part of your code where you access `name`.

Comment: OP is asking about how to access the variable in the debugger.  Not how to get it to compile.  I have the same issue.  This answer is not helpful.